# Stats with random numbers

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I want to create 7 stats for a character, randomly generating a value from 3-21, with the stat's sum being no higher than 91. I've tried arranging the stats into an array, and just going through them like this:

```
1) add random(15) to each array member
2) computing the total, subtracting from the 91 maximum
3) dividing this difference by 7
4) do step 1 with random(difference) adding it to the stat
5) Until I hit the 91 total.
```

Doing this a few hundred times I seem to get a curve where the 5,6, and 7th stats tend to be higher. And sometimes I hit the 4 or 5th stat and there are no more numbers to be added, meaning then that the first few stats get the most points. I think I am approaching this the wrong way to begin with. Any ideas? I have tunnel vision at this point I think.

Comment: Questions about problems with your code need to include the code. If you're not showing us what you're doing, it's impossible to tell you what you're doing incorrectly.

Comment: @KenWhite I might call this a grey area... he described the algorithm adequately and the problems are, by inspection, related to the algorithm and not the code.

Comment: @J...: Sorry, but I disagree. You can describe the algorithm accurately but fail to implement it according to the description. It's impossible to tell what the problem might be without seeing the code that actually implements the algo, and "Any ideas?" isn't a specific question.

Comment: @KenWhite I would agree in the case where the results differed from the expected results of the stated algorithm.  In this case the stated algorithm simply will not work - while there may or may not be problems with the code, the algorithm as stated is defective.  `I'm trying to make 9 by adding 5 to 3 but it didn't work - I got 8 instead.  Any ideas?` -- in my mind that's sufficient.  If the algorithm was that five and four were added, however, and the result was eight *then* I would expect to see some code.

Comment: My take is that if the asker has not succeeded in telling the computer what is needed, then it seems likely that the asker may also fail to tell us. If code were presented then we'd know, rather than having to guess, or trust that the description matched the code. An SSCCE is needed here.

Comment: This question has a scent of homework. Is it just me?

Comment: @AndreaRaimondi it actually seems more like a bedroom project to obsolete the D20

Comment: Pick **one** language tag. Since I only see pseudocode I'm removing the other tags.

Comment: @AndreaRaimondi - Clearly not HW. This looks like game programming.

Comment: @AndreaRaimondi If it's homework, that doesn't mean there's something wrong with it though.

Comment: Not homework, just something I was goofing around with that might be game related at some point. Thanks for all the comments though. Basically the idea was to give the player a random list of stats, give them say 14-16 point to add with no one stat receiving more than 5 points of those points and no stat receiving less than 1. This is easily done mentally, but algorithmically, I was struggling a bit. The pascal tag was just for reference since that is the language I would proceed in.

Comment: 2 Downvotes? really people? It was a simple quesion for help and got a downvote. The elitism at stackoverflow astounds me sometimes. I bet I can guess from the comments who the downvoters are lol.

Comment: Why don't you just generate 7 random numbers between 1 and 100, and afterwards scale them down so that sum up to (roughly) 91?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're overthinking this.  I might do something like this :

```
const
  STAT_QTY = 7;
  STATSUM_MAX = 91;
  STAT_MIN = 3;
  STAT_MAX = 21;

type
  TStatArray = Array [0..STAT_QTY-1] of integer;
```

Then in implementation :

```
function GenerateStats : TStatArray;
var statArr : TStatArray;
    i, statSum, excess, debit : integer;
    done : boolean;
begin
  Randomize;
  done := false;
  while not done do begin
    done := true;
    statSum := 0;
    for i := 0 to STAT_QTY - 1 do begin
      statArr[i] := STAT_MIN + Random(STAT_MAX - STAT_MIN);
      statSum := statSum + statArr[i];
    end;
    if statSum > STATSUM_MAX then begin
      excess := statSum - STATSUM_MAX;
      debit := excess div STAT_QTY + 1;
      for i := 0 to STAT_QTY -1 do begin
        statArr[i] := statArr[i] - debit;
      end;
    end;
    for i := 0 to STAT_QTY -1 do begin
      if statArr[i] < STAT_MIN then done := false;
    end;
  end;
  result := statArr;
end;
```

This generates a list of random stats in the range 3-21.  If the sum is more than 91 then divide the excess by the number of stats (use `div` then round up the answer) and subtract an equal number from each.  In the rare case that you end up with stats less than three, just do it again.  Job done.

Tested over 2000 iterations I get average stats of :

```
 [1] : 11.13893053  
 [2] : 11.15692154  
 [3] : 11.16141929  
 [4] : 11.11444278  
 [5] : 11.10194903  
 [6] : 10.9800100   
 [7] : 10.86856572
```

That's a total average of 11.07 with a standard deviation of 0.11 - certainly about what one would expect from a generally random set with your construction parameters.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it will do nicely at this point. I am just an extremely amateur coder trying to pursue a long time project that had me scratching my head a bit. I would upvote had I enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's C-ish pseudo code for a slightly different approach, assuming a suitable `random(N)` function that returns numbers in the range `0 - N-1`.

```
int stats[7], deficit = 70;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
  stats[i] = 3;               // initial assignments of the minimum to each stat
while (deficit)
{ int tmp = random(7);        // pick a random stat to bump
  if (stats[tmp] == 21)       // but not if it's already at max
    continue;
  ++stats[tmp];
  --deficit;
}
```

Assuming your `random()` is uniformly distributed, that should give pretty good results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Pascal is my poison of choice since I learned it first and have not pursued another language since. I evolved into delphi and have pretty much stuck with it for little personal projects since.